# Powershell loop exits early

Tags: windows, powershell, system

This is extremely stupid, but my loop is exiting before it gets to the second loop apparently.

What the script does is counts the hardware bus and function number from ethernet cards on a server (usually contain at least 2 ports or more).  The bus usually corresponds to a chip/card in the server, and the function number usually the specific port.

Example scenario - a server with 2 dual-port ethernet cards might look like this when you run get-netadapterhardwareinfo:

```
name     Bus Function
----     --- --------
PORT4      2        1
PORT3      2        0
B1 Port2   1        1 
B1 Port1   1        0
```

You can see the script runs on "bus 1" but then the loop exits before "bus 2" can be processed.

This line is supposed to handle it

`for($i = 1; $i -le $buscount.Maximum; $i++)`

and the "less than or equal" should evaluate as true for the second loop.  I put in some write-hosts at the end to debug the loop, it seems to exit.

FULL SCRIPT:

```
#BEGIN
#collect hardware information, determine ports.
$allnicinfo = Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo | Select Name, InstanceID, InterfaceDescription, BusNumber, FunctionNumber

#determine how many adapters exist
$buscount = Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo | select -ExpandProperty busnumber | measure-object -maximum | select Maximum

#improve the bus count method
for($i = 1; $i -le $buscount.Maximum; $i++)
    {
    $bus = $i

    $funccount= @()
    $funccount = $allnicinfo | where-object {$_.busnumber -eq $i} | select -expandproperty functionnumber | measure-object -Maximum | select Maximum
    for($i = 0; $i -le $funccount.Maximum; $i++)
        {
        $nic = Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo | where {($_.busnumber -eq $bus) -and ($_.functionnumber -eq $i)}
        $port = $i + 1
        Rename-NetAdapter $nic.Name "B$bus Port$port"
        }
    write-host $bus
    write-host $i

    }
```

Comment: Where does `BusNumber` exist?  I see in your example that there's a `Bus` property, but no `BusNumber`.  Additionally, your `$allnicinfo` variable should have a `.Count` property since it's an array.

Comment: $It's a property of the get-netadapterhardwareinfo cmdlet.  Doesn't seem to have a count, why I'm not certain.  You are probably right that I should be storing it as an array, I don't think it will fix my loop problem either way however.

Comment: Why are you using `For` instead of `ForEach` loops?  Seems a bit convoluted to follow.  All you're doing is renaming adapters

Comment: No great reason, seems like for what I wanted to do (loop through each bus and rename adapters based on functionnumber) it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your logic, here's a cleaned up version of your script that should work better.  First we create an array of `$Nics` to perform calculations against so you don't need to constantly poll your hardware (slow).  It's also a bad practice to mask variable names (using `$i` in both of your loops).

```
## Collect hardware information, determine ports
$Nics = @(
    Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo |
        Select-Object -Property @('Name', 'InstanceID', 'InterfaceDescription', 'BusNumber', 'FunctionNumber')
)

## Rename logic
For ($i = 0; $i -le $Nics.Count; $i++)
{
    $FunctionCount = (($Nics | Where-Object { $_.BusNumber -eq $i }).FunctionNumber | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum

    For ($j = 0; $j -le $FunctionCount; $j++)
    {
        $Nic = $Nics | Where-Object { $_.BusNumber -eq $i -and $_.FunctionNumber -eq $j }
        Rename-NetAdapter -Name $Nic.Name -NewName "B$i Port$($j + 1)" -PassThru -WhatIf
    }
}
```

This is safe to run, do note `-WhatIf`

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!   I'll try to avoid that other approach!

Answer (score 0):

I was a little confused by your code and think you could do it a little simpler. See below

```
$NetAdapterHardwareInfo = Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo
foreach ( $NetAdapter in $NetAdapterHardwareInfo )
{
    $NewName = 'B{0} Port{1}' -f $NetAdapter.Bus,($NetAdapter.Function + 1) 
    Rename-NetAdapter $NetAdapter.Name -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
}
```

If you leave the `-WhatIf` you would get output like this:

> What if: Rename-NetAdapter -Name 'Wi-Fi' -NewName 'B58 Port1'
>
> What if: Rename-NetAdapter -Name 'Ethernet' -NewName 'B0 Port7'

You can just remove the `-WhatIf` when you want to put it in production.